# App Services Premium P1v3 level not available in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-app-service-plans

We have created a new App Service Plan Premium P1v3 in Azure - France Central, but it is not showing as available when publishing apps from Visual Studio.
Any other Service Plan with a lower rate is available.
Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: probably because v3 was just recently released. Have you updated to the latest version of VS? If not, you should raise that with product support I guess

Comment: Thanks Silent. Yes, we have the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 installed. v:16.8.2 of 11/20/2020.

Comment: then I would guess the plugin hasn't been updated yet to cater for the new SKU. Anyway, you probably know that in most cases you do not want to really deploy from VS but from a proper CI/CD pipeline ;)